# Replace All Cells in Column G with a Formula

Tags: excel, vba

Am I missing something here? I'm getting a 1004 during debug

```
    Sub perc()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("G2:G" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF((AND(A2<>"",F2>0)),F2/C2, "")"
    End Sub
```

Comment: First - you need to qualify your objects (*I see 3 unqualified objects: `Range, Rows, & Range again`*) and second you need to double up on your empty string quote (*2 instances*).

Comment: The lastRow line of code counts the rows.....

Comment: you have a typo in `"=IF((AND(A2<>"",F2>0)),F2/C2, "")"` Try this `"=IF((AND(A2<>"""",F2>0)),F2/C2, """")"`

Comment: I wouldn't consider that a typo @SiddharthRout rather common mistake of not knowing the quotes need to be doubled up for them to be read inside the `.Formula`

Comment: @urdearboy: Yeah you do make a valid point. Then I guess should be closed as a duplicate.. Lot of questions which deal with this. Did upvote your answer though :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout ha very true on duplicate. When you said typo I read the formula a few times looking for the typo. I started to question if I forgot how to spell `IF` or `AND` haha

Answer (score 1):

1. **You need to qualify your objects** - What workbook/worksheet does the `Range` and `Rows` object exist on? The assumed object references may be incorrect
2. You need to double up on your blank quote strings inside the formula

---

```
Sub Perc()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("G2:G" & lr).Formula = "=IF((AND(A2<>"""", F2>0)), F2/C2, """")"

End Sub
```